# Image are not loading correctly using URL.createObjectURL Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, url, blob

This is my DefaultHeaderComponent that i am using a Header. My problem is that when i use router to navigate to another component, the img will not show, UNTILL i interact with that component somehow like for example by clicking on a button or anything. I dont understand this. why is this happening and how can i solve it ?

```
export class DefaultHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  userImg!: string;

  constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private sidebarService: SidebarService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setUserImg();
  }

  public triggerSidebar(): void {
    this.sidebarService.isOpen = !this.sidebarService.isOpen;
  }

  private setUserImg() {
    this.profileService
      .getUserProfilePictureById(this.authService.getUserIdFromLocalStorage()!)
      .subscribe({
        next: (x) => {
          this.userImg = URL.createObjectURL(x);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        },
      });
  }
}
```

```
 <div class="header-btn">
<img class="user-image" src="{{ userImg }}" (click)="triggerSidebar()" />
```

Comment: Hi, did you try to change syntax to [src]="userImg" ? You might have to sanitize it first in order to be able to use it like that.